# SQLiteException: no such column: basal (code 1)

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm working with databases and I have the following DataBaseHandling class:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_MEASURES = "measuresDataBase";

// Measures table name
private static final String TABLE_MEASURES = "measures";

// Measures Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
private static final String KEY_TIME_HOUR = "timeHour";
private static final String KEY_TIME_MINUTE = "timeMinute";
private static final String KEY_BE_INTAKE = "be_intake";
private static final String KEY_GLUCOSE = "glucose";
private static final String KEY_BOLUS = "bolus";
private static final String KEY_BASAL = "basal";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_MEASURES, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_MEASURES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MEASURES + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_DATE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_TIME_HOUR + " INTEGER NOT NULL," + KEY_TIME_MINUTE
            + " INTEGER NOT NULL," + KEY_BE_INTAKE + " REAL NOT NULL,"
            + KEY_GLUCOSE + " REAL NOT NULL," + KEY_BOLUS
            + " REAL NOT NULL," + KEY_BASAL + "REAL NOT NULL," + ")";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_MEASURES_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MEASURES);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

// Adding new contact
public void addMeasure(Measures m) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_DATE, m.getDate());
    values.put(KEY_TIME_HOUR, m.getTimeHour());
    values.put(KEY_TIME_MINUTE, m.getTimeMinute());
    values.put(KEY_BE_INTAKE, m.getBolus());
    values.put(KEY_GLUCOSE, m.getGlucose()); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_BOLUS, m.getBolus()); // Contact Phone Number
    values.put(KEY_BASAL, m.getBasal());

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_MEASURES, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

public Measures getLastMeasure(String date) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_MEASURES, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_DATE, KEY_TIME_HOUR, KEY_TIME_MINUTE, KEY_BE_INTAKE,
            KEY_GLUCOSE, KEY_BOLUS, KEY_BASAL }, KEY_DATE + "=?",
            new String[] { date }, null, null,
            KEY_TIME_HOUR + " DESC, " + KEY_TIME_MINUTE + " DESC", "1");
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Measures m = new Measures(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(0)), // id
            cursor.getString(1), // date
            Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)), // timeHour
            Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)), // timeMinute
            Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(4)), // BE intake
            Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(5)), // glucose
            Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(6)), // bolus
            Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(7)) // basal

    );
    // return m
    return m;
}

// Getting All Measures
public List<Measures> getAllMeasures() {
    List<Measures> measureList = new ArrayList<Measures>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_MEASURES;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Measures m = new Measures();
            m.setId(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(0)));
            m.setDate(cursor.getString(1));
            m.setTimeHour(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
            m.setTimeMinute(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)));
            m.setBe_intake(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(4)));
            m.setGlucose(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(5)));
            m.setBolus(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(6)));
            m.setBasal(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(7)));
            // Adding measure to list
            measureList.add(m);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return measureList;
}
```

The logcat shows:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: basal (code 1):, while compiling: SELECT id, date, timeHour, timeMinute, be_intake, glucose, bolus, basal FROM mesaures WHERE date=? ORDER BY timeHour DESC LIMIT 1

I would thank all your help

My Logcat (after resolving the first problem)

> 08-27 14:34:51.316: E/AndroidRuntime(772): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   08-27 14:34:51.316: E/AndroidRuntime(772): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
>   08-27 14:34:51.316: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:418)
>   08-27 14:34:51.316: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
>   08-27 14:34:51.316: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
>   08-27 14:34:51.316: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at com.example.t1diabetes.DatabaseHandler.getLastMeasure(DatabaseHandler.java:92)
>   08-27 14:34:51.316: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at com.example.t1diabetes.Mymeasures.calculateBasal(Mymeasures.java:263)
>   08-27 14:34:51.316: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at com.example.t1diabetes.Mymeasures.access$1(Mymeasures.java:262)
>   08-27 14:34:51.316: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at com.example.t1diabetes.Mymeasures$1.onClick(Mymeasures.java:99)
>   08-27 14:34:51.316: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
>   08-27 14:34:51.316: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
>   08-27 14:34:51.316: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>   08-27 14:34:51.316: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   08-27 14:34:51.316: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   08-27 14:34:51.316: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
>   08-27 14:34:51.316: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   08-27 14:34:51.316: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   08-27 14:34:51.316: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>   08-27 14:34:51.316: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>   08-27 14:34:51.316: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: post your table structure

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Comment: No, now I have a CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Comment: I added it to the main post

Answer (score 5):

Use a space after KEY_BASAL  column  . As your table column name was not correct , the table was created without this column. So after modifying code re-install your database or change version.Then you will get correct table with columns

```
String CREATE_MEASURES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MEASURES + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_DATE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_TIME_HOUR + " INTEGER NOT NULL," + KEY_TIME_MINUTE
            + " INTEGER NOT NULL," + KEY_BE_INTAKE + " REAL NOT NULL,"
            + KEY_GLUCOSE + " REAL NOT NULL," + KEY_BOLUS
            + " REAL NOT NULL," + KEY_BASAL + " REAL NOT NULL" + ")";


if (cursor != null && cursor .getCount()>0){

        cursor.moveToFirst();

///

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I made the changes but now I have: CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Comment: So you are getting exception. Check table has row .If exist then check your select query condition .

Comment: I've checked both but I don't see the problem yet. It used to work without the basal column, but I added it in the usual way and now it doesn't

Comment: As count row is zero, how will you iterate. without checking count row , you will get indexoutofobound exception.so re install your apps. Check manually to retrieve row.

Comment: ADD row into  table then try to retrieve. check query log

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem that you have missed a space at the Key_basal and also placed an extra comma at the end of your onCreate method. Your code :

```
// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
String CREATE_MEASURES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MEASURES + "("
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_DATE + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_TIME_HOUR + " INTEGER NOT NULL," + KEY_TIME_MINUTE
        + " INTEGER NOT NULL," + KEY_BE_INTAKE + " REAL NOT NULL,"
        + KEY_GLUCOSE + " REAL NOT NULL," + KEY_BOLUS
        + " REAL NOT NULL," + KEY_BASAL + "REAL NOT NULL," + ")";

db.execSQL(CREATE_MEASURES_TABLE);
}
```

It should be :

```
// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
String CREATE_MEASURES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MEASURES + "("
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_DATE + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_TIME_HOUR + " INTEGER NOT NULL," + KEY_TIME_MINUTE
        + " INTEGER NOT NULL," + KEY_BE_INTAKE + " REAL NOT NULL,"
        + KEY_GLUCOSE + " REAL NOT NULL," + KEY_BOLUS
        + " REAL NOT NULL," + KEY_BASAL + " REAL NOT NULL" + ")";

db.execSQL(CREATE_MEASURES_TABLE);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I made the changes but now I have: CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Answer (score 2):

Remove `,` End of Query

```
KEY_BASAL + "REAL NOT NULL," + ")";
                          ^
                          | Here
```

And Use Space For Concat Strings

```
KEY_BASAL + "REAL NOT NULL," + ")";
             ^
             | Here
```

GoodLuck

Answer (score 1):

Autoincrement  `KEY_ID` or put some data to `KEY_ID` as well as put your full log cat here:

```
String CREATE_MEASURES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MEASURES + "("
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_DATE + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_TIME_HOUR + " INTEGER NOT NULL," + KEY_TIME_MINUTE
        + " INTEGER NOT NULL," + KEY_BE_INTAKE + " REAL NOT NULL,"
        + KEY_GLUCOSE + " REAL NOT NULL," + KEY_BOLUS
        + " REAL NOT NULL," + KEY_BASAL + " REAL NOT NULL" + ")";
```

Comment: Thanks. I made the changes but now I have: CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Comment: you are trying to retrive data first .What u ve to do is 1st put the method which is sending data to the database and then call the method which is retrieving data

Comment: But I can't do that because I have a "Save" Button that only store data in the database if everything is fine, and first we should see the results, and to calculate the results I need to access to the last element introduced in the database...

Comment: check cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while using junit tests. And my error was simple but evil.

I mixed `getContext()` and `getMockConetext()`.